# Time formatting (HH:MM:SS) in any Smalltalk dialect

Tags: string, time, smalltalk

I have three integer values, say

```
h := 3.
m := 19.
s := 8.
```

I would like to produce the string `'03:19:08'`. I know how to turn a number into a string, and even pad it with a zero if necessary. So as a first pass I wrote this absolutely horrific code:

```
h < 10 ifTrue: [hs := '0', (h asString)] ifFalse: [hs := h asString].
m < 10 ifTrue: [ms := '0', (m asString)] ifFalse: [ms := m asString].
s < 10 ifTrue: [ss := '0', (s asString)] ifFalse: [ss := s asString].
Transcript show: hs, ':', ms, ':', ss.
Transcript nl.
```

Now obviously I need to clean this up and so was wondering, among other things what the most idiomatic Smalltalk approach would be here. Could it be something like (not legal Smalltalk obviously):

```
aCollectionWithHMS each [c | padWithZero] join ':'
```

I found a discussion on streams with a print method taking a `separatedBy` argument but wouldn't there be a simpler way to do things just with strings?

Or perhaps there is a more elegant way to pad the three components and then I could just return `hs, ':', ms, ':', ss` ?

Or, is there an interface to POSIX time formatting (or something similar) common to all Smalltalks? I know GNU Smalltalk can link to C but this is way too much overkill for this simple problem IMHO.

**EDIT**

I got a little closer:

```
z := {h . m . s} collect: [:c | c < 10 ifTrue: ['0', c asString] ifFalse: [c asString]].
(Transcript show: ((z at: 1), ':',  (z at: 2), ':', (z at: 3))) nl.
```

But the direct access of collection elements makes me sad. I found a [page documenting the joining method `asStringWith`](http://rigaux.org/language-study/syntax-across-languages-per-language/Smalltalk.html) but that method is unsupported, it seems in GNU Smalltalk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do this in Pharo:

```
String streamContents: [:stream |
  {h.m.s}
    do: [:token | token printOn: stream base: 10 nDigits: 2]
    separatedBy: [stream nextPut: $:]]
```

Explanation:

1. The `streamContents:` message answers with the contents of the `WriteStream` represented by the formal block argument `stream`.
2. The `do:separatedBy:` message enumerates the tokens `h`, `m` and `s` evaluating the `do:` block for each of them and inserting the evaluation of the second block between consecutive tokens.
3. The `printOn:base:nDigits:` message dumps on the `stream` the base `10` representation of the `token` padded to `2` digits.

If the dialect you are using doesn't have the `printOn:base:nDigits:` method (or any appropriate variation of it), you can do the following:

```
String streamContents: [:stream |
  {h.m.s}
    do: [:token |
      token < 10 ifTrue: [stream nextPut: $0].
      stream nextPutAll: token asString]
    separatedBy: [stream nextPut: $:]]
```

Finally, if you think you will be using this a lot, I would recommend adding the message `hhmmss` to `Time` (instance side), implemented as above with `self hours` instead of `h`, etc. Then it would be a matter of sending

```
(Time hour: h minute: m second: s) hhmmss
```

assuming you have these three quantities instead of a `Time` object, which would be unusual. Otherwise, you would only need something like

```
aTime hhmmss
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

Here is another way that will work on any dialect:

```
{h.m.s}
  inject: ''
  into: [:r :t | | pad colon |
    pad := t < 10 ifTrue: ['0'] ifFalse: [''].
    colon := r isEmpty ifTrue: [''] ifFalse: [':'].
    r , colon, pad, t asString]
```

The `inject:into:` method builds its result from the `inject:` argument (the empty `String` in this case) and keeps replacing the formal block argument `r` with the value of the previous iteration. The second formal argument `t` is replaced with the corresponding element of each iteration.

---

**ADDENDUM 2**

```
time := '00:00:00' copy.
{h asString. m asString. s asString} withIndexDo: [:t :i |
  time at: i - 1 * 3 + 2 put: t last.
  t size = 2 ifTrue: [time at: i - 1 * 3 + 1 put: t first]].
^time
```

The `copy` is necessary to make sure that the literal is not modified.

Comment: Looks nice. I went with addendum 1, but used `{'' . h . m . s} fold:` Would not have been able to proceed without that insight.